# symfony2 doctrine manytoone relationship

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I believe it's that there must be a simple solution for my issue but I can't get that to work and I'm not sure why.

Scenario:
I've got 2 entities: Bike and Review, relationship is OneToMany:

```
/**
 * Bike
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="BikeRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\Table(name="bike")
 */
class Bike
{
...
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Review", mappedBy="bike", cascade={"persist"}, fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
     */
    private $reviews;
...
}

/**
 * Review
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ReviewRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="review")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Review
{
    ...

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Bike", inversedBy="reviews", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="bike_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $bike;
    ....
}
```

Getters and setters has been generated by doctrine.

On the frontend I've got a form where bike is as a hidden field because there is an autocomplete field with ajax request. So in the controller if $form->isValid() I'm getting bike id from the hidden field, search database for that bike and set bike as below:

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
    if ($bikeId) {
        $bike = $this->em->getRepository('BikeBundle:Bike')->findOneBy(array('id' => $bikeId));
        $review->setBike($bike);
    }
    $this->em->persist($review);
    $this->em->flush();
}
```

And this is always giving me NULL in the database for bike_id. Any idea what could be wrong? I have tried to dump $review before persist and I can get the bike details so I don't know what's going wrong. In the entity setBike() method I can get any value of that Bike object except getId() is returning NULL.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just a comment - you will find that `findOneBy(array('id' => $bikeId))` is exactly the same as the helper function `find($bikeId)`

Answer (score 0):

1. you don't need to persist an existing entity, so you can just save your entity like

   > $review->setBike($bike);
   >       $this->em->flush();
2. try to check if doctrine really returns any entities..I'm afraid if it doesn't return Bike entity

UPD: Also try to check the namespace of Bike Entity class. It seems like it is wrong in your case, because usually it looks like "AcmeBikeBundle:Bike"